# When is the quotient algebra of a unital C* algebra helpful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal A$ be a unital C* algebra.

Which properties does $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal A$ has to have for it to make sense to form the quotient algebra $\mathcal A / \mathcal B$?

In cases where this construction makes sense, does $\mathcal A / \mathcal B$ have any special structure/properties that are helpful?
Put differently, for what kind of standard questions does it help to consider $\mathcal A / \mathcal B$ because it has desired properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a closed $*$-ideal of $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{B}$ is again a unital C*-algebra. This can be found in every introduction to C*-algebras. And of course this basic construction is used everywhere, so that it doesn't make sense to start a list of applications here. A well-known example is the [Calkin algebra](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin-Algebra). In the commutative case, we have $C(X)/I(A) \cong C(A)$ for closed subspaces $A \subseteq X$ with vanishing ideal $I(A)=\{f : f|_A=0\}$.

Comment: May I ask in what sense is $*$-ideal closed? Is it closed in the topological sense, that is $I = \overline{I}$? Or closed under some operation? E.g. vector subspaces are closed under the vector addition and scalar multiplication. I've read on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) "closed under taking adjoints", which I understand as follows $\forall a \in I \implies a^* \in I$?